# Using enable_if on a defaulted template argument for a constexpr lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, default-arguments

I'm trying to write a generic function that will always return a `-1`. I want the template argument list to default to `int`. I'm trying to use `std::enable_if` or `std::enable_if_t` to test if the type `T` is a valid arithmetic type by using `std::is_arithmetic` or `std::is_arithmetic_v`. I'm having syntax issues to be able to get this to compile correctly. Here is what my lambda looks like:

```
template<typename T = int,
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>> >
static constexpr T negative_one = [](){ 
    return static_cast<T>(-1); 
};
```

This is a very trivial function and concept, but the compiler wants to complain that the default argument is not at the end of the argument list... What would its proper definition look like?

This is how I would be using it:

```
{
    int i = negative_one();
    float f = negative_one<float>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-type optional template argument for sfinae. Your type needs to be a lambda type (not `T`) if you want to call it/pass it as a predicate. You can achieve this with automatic type deduction.

```
template<typename T = int, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
static constexpr auto negative_one = [](){ 
    return static_cast<T>(-1); 
};
```

Another option could be to use a function instead of a lambda:

```
template<typename T = int, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
static constexpr T negative_one() { 
    return static_cast<T>(-1); 
};
```

Comment: I appreciate both cases, but I may want to pass this in as a predicate where a lambda can be used! But I didn't know about calling the lambda at that site of declaration-definition... I was also missing the `class = ` part too. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: There is one issue though when I use the lambda, it's complaining that `int i = negative_one;` is missing the required template argument. The entire purpose of this was for `int` to be the default where I don't have to tell it to be an `int` but for other types such as `float`, `double`, `char`, `bool` they would have to be expressed.

Comment: `int i = negative_one<>();`

Comment: Yes, this is a simple trivial case, but from this model, I can construct all of my constants... Now I can make my `negate` `lambda` after the same fashion that will negate any value that is passed by reference.

Comment: Works like a charm! I now have this and my negate lambda up and working!

Comment: Now, if C++ allowed for variable templates that can be of a constexpr type, then I probably wouldn't necessarily need this, but my compiler even with c++17 doesn't fully support them, especially outside of a class object...

Comment: what compiler? gcc and clang both fully support C++17

Comment: Visual Studio haha

Comment: Prefer `std::enable_if_f<cond<T>, int> = 0` over `typename = std::enable_if_f<cond<T>>`, the later can be hijacked (`negative_one<SomeType, int>`).

Comment: Yeah, I can use some forms of variable templates, but I don't have the full support of them... when I get around to it and clean up my pc, I do believe that VS2019 does support them especially with C++20.

Comment: this gets much much nicer with C++20 concepts https://godbolt.org/z/ETv3YW

Comment: and yeah, follow Jarod42's advice

Comment: I tried changing it to Jarod's form but the compiler is going crazy now...

Comment: I think I figured it out... it didn't like the `=` right next to closing `>` for `std::enable_if_t`, once I added a space in between them, the compiler stopped complaining...

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I was looking for. I think I'll go with the lambda version as it is a `nameless` - `anonymous` function... and it's all done at compile time. Now all that is left is to just put it in its appropriate `namespace`!